# How do I open a file that locked?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems

I need to view my `ntuser.dat.LOG1` file, but I get the error that it's locked because something else has it open. How can I force Notepad or some other program to open this file. I really need to see what's in it so I can restore lost environment variables.

Comment: Not sure if you can. But you can try making a copy of the file, and open the copy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try unlocking it with [unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/). Just install it (careful with the shareware crap bundled in the installer), right click your file and click Unlocker.

Comment: Unlocker won't help in this case. ntuser.dat.log1 is a logfile that is being written to constantly as long as the current user is logged in. unlocker won't be able to release the lock and thus suggests to reboot the pc to unlock the file. Upon boot, that file will be written to again, thus unlocker fails.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to bear in mind about that particular file:

1. That is part of your registry user hive.  It is protected by Windows at all times while you're logged in, so there is no way to unlock it.  If you need to open it, you can reboot the computer and log in with another account.
2. The NTUSER.LOG* files are only change journals, and don't contain your actual registry data. They only exist so that the computer can reconstruct the last few operations that happened to the main NTUSER.DAT file in case it somehow gets corrupted.

It sounds like NTUSER.DAT did get corrupted, so you can use the trick above to gain access to it.  It's a binary file, however, and an incomplete one at that. Neither Regedit nor Notepad will be able to make sense of it.